# Flask: How to read a file in application root?

Tags: python, flask

My Flask application structure looks like

```
application_top/
         application/
                    static/
                          english_words.txt
                    templates/
                             main.html
                     urls.py
                     views.py
         runserver.py
```

When I run the `runserver.py`, it starts the server at `localhost:5000`.
In my `views.py`, I try to open the file `english.txt` as

```
f = open('/static/english.txt')
```

It gives error `IOError: No such file or directory`

How can I access this file?

Comment: `static` is at the same level as `views.py`, try without `/` ? However, I suggest do full path make use of `__file__` and  `os.path....` module.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I think the issue is you put `/` in the path. Remove `/` because `static` is at the same level as `views.py`.

I suggest making a `settings.py` the same level as `views.py` Or many Flask users prefer to use `__init__.py` but I don't.

```
application_top/
    application/
          static/
              english_words.txt
          templates/
              main.html
          urls.py
          views.py
          settings.py
    runserver.py
```

If this is how you would set up, try this:

```
#settings.py
import os
# __file__ refers to the file settings.py 
APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))   # refers to application_top
APP_STATIC = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'static')
```

Now in your views, you can simply do:

```
import os
from settings import APP_STATIC
with open(os.path.join(APP_STATIC, 'english_words.txt')) as f:
    f.read()
```

Adjust the path and level based on your requirement.

Comment: See [this snippet](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/102/) if you are using `config.py`

Comment: Great!! Works for me.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a simple alternative to CppLearners answer:

```
from flask import current_app

with current_app.open_resource('static/english_words.txt') as f:
    f.read()
```

See the documentation here: [Flask.open_resource](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.open_resource)

Answer (score 3):

The flask `app` also has a property named `root_path` to resolve the root directory as well as an `instance_path` property for the particular `app` directory without requiring the `os` module, though I like @jpihl's answer.

```py
with open(f'{app.root_path}/static/english_words.txt', 'r') as f:
    f.read()
```