# Accessing a file inside a docker container using an absolute import

Tags: docker, flask

I'm trying to access a specific file within a folder inside my docker container and getting the error `No such file or directory: '/api/assets/dna/human.txt'`

I'm using `with open('/api/assets/dna/human.txt'), 'r')` from the `dna.py`  file inside my models directory.

My folder structure is

```
-api
 -models
  -dna.py
 -assets
  -dna
   -human.txt
-Dockerfile
```

However, if `human.txt` is in the root folder like so -

```
-api
 -models
  -dna.py
 -assets
  -dna
-Dockerfile
-human.txt
```

`with open('human.txt'), 'r') as f:` works just fine.

I feel silly for not being able to figure out why the absolute import is not able to find the `human.txt` file when its not located in the root folder, so thank you very much for pointing out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14825787/flask-how-to-read-a-file-in-application-root

Comment: Thank you very much! The issue was as medial as removing the `/`.

Comment: yeah, / is for the root, and your app may not be at the root